# How to link my Kuthi.py file with my .xml file after clicking submit?

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have a python file which is designed using pyqt5 designer, i have .xml file which is the expected output, in this .xml file, there is spaces which will be replaced according to the desired input values?

[image]

like this, address will be in address location.

Here is my kuthi.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 330, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 190, 261, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 260, 111, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 230, 101, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 111, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 261, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 81, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 130, 261, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 200, 111, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 160, 261, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Address :"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Father\'s Name :"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Full Name :"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Date of Birth :"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Mother\'s Name :"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is a unclear, can you please clarify? What does the linked image have to do with the code above?

Comment: The link image is a screenshot of the expected output page, my input values will be replaced on that linked image page.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still unclear. What is the xml file you wrote about? What do you want do achieve? There is nothing really helpful in your code, it just creates an interface that does nothing.

Comment: Dear, can you share me your fb or whatsapp or any ?